# Unable render neural network structural graph on kaggle notebook

Tags: kaggle

I got this message on Kaggle notebook

```
'Failed to import pydot. You must `pip install pydot` and install graphviz (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/), ', 'for `pydotprint` to work.'
```

Rendering NN structural graphs doesn't work. What is the problem? Is it a problem on Kaggle side? Code I was running was very simple.

Comment: The solution is to include ```!pip install pydot !pip install pydotplus !pip install graphviz ``` . But it depends on where the cell is located, it should be somewhere in the beginning of the notebook, in my case it was the second. Otherwise, I got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to turn on internet support on your kaggle notebook and install the following packages via pip packet manager:

```
!pip install pydot
!pip install pydotplus
!pip install graphviz
```